# Why is the result of my sourced code not displaying in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am having difficulty displaying the result of a sourced script in RMarkdown.

As an example, I have a simple R script called 'Values.R' which contains only:

`values <- c(5, 3, 7)`

Then I have an RMarkdown document 'Values Report.Rmd' which looks like this:

````
---
title: Values report.
date: 2023-11-21
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE]

source("filepath/Values.R")

```

There are two values we are interested in, being `values[1]` and `values[2]`. We are not interested in `values[3]`.
````

You can replace filepath with whatever your filepath is.

--

**Output after clicking 'knit' button**:

"There are two values we are interested in, being `values[1]` and `values[2]`. We are not interested in `values[3]`."

**Expected output**:

"There are two values we are interested in, being 5 and 3. We are not interested in 7."

--

I have also tried to use `rmarkdown::render("Values Report.Rmd")` and got the same output described above (not what I am expecting). There is one difference though when I use `rmarkdown::render` -- I can see that `values` appears in my Environment tab.

I know I could copy the code into the RMarkdown file rather than source it, but my actual script is much more complex and I would prefer to keep it separate to the .Rmd file.

**How can I amend my .Rmd file so I get the expected output?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting the r after your tick, otherwise it will just format it as code, so do this:

```
`r  values[1]`
```